# integrating area of triangle

Tags: calculus, integration

i working on area between curve and it has combination between curve and straight line and i got into trouble.
this is the statement of the problem

find enclosed area by $y = \sqrt{x-1}$ and $y = 3-x$ and $x$ axis

the intersection point between to function is $(2,1)$ and the area is combination between curved area and a triangle
but how exactly i integrating that triangle (with height of 1 (lies from y=0 to y=1) and base 1 (lies from x=2 to x=3))
the area should be $\frac{1}{2}$ but if i use $y = 3-x$ or i should write $(y = 3-x)- 0$(x axis) 
 and integrate it from 3 to 2 in respect of x axis and make closed bound to $x$ axis, it would turn into mess it and would resulted $2.5$, that's a whole different answer so how i solve area of this triangle?
[image]

Comment: The integral you describe doesn't come out to $2.5$, so check that work.  But really, this problem should be a $y$-integration.

Comment: i mean it is $3x - \frac{x^2}{2}$ with upper and lower limit 3 and 2 so how i can get result you mentioned?

Comment: If you plug in $3$ you get $9/2$.  If you plug in $2$ you get $4$.   $9/2 - 4 = 1/2$ which is the correct area of that triangle.  We're all wondering what the problem is.

Comment: oh i'm very sorry , this is so embarassing

Comment: You're allowed a mistake once in a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x-1}dx+\frac{1}{2}\times (3-2)\times 1$$